# Реализовать увеличение скорости в простой игре (Snake)

Tags: javascript, canvas

Есть простая игра Змейка, написана на js c  использованием canvas/
Нужно реализовать увеличение скорости  игры каждые 10 съеденых точек.

Возможно это сделать в рамках текущего кода?  Я имею ввиду что для обновления холста используеться SetInterval. И мне кажется  что код с данными методом так не оптимизировать. :(
Вообщем сам вопрос. Как это можно сделать? И можно пример.
Спасибо

https://jsfiddle.net/dedn/wsbvfmzr/

```
(((drawModule) => {

  const btn = document.getElementById('btn');
  btn.addEventListener("click", () => { drawModule.init();});

  document.onkeydown = event => {
  const  keyCode = event.keyCode;

    switch(keyCode) {

      case 37:
        if (direction != 'right') {
          direction = 'left';
        }
        console.log('left');
        break;

      case 39:
        if (direction != 'left') {
          direction = 'right';
          console.log('right');
        }
        break;

      case 38:
        if (direction != 'down') {
          direction = 'up';
          console.log('up');
        }
        break;

      case 40:
        if (direction != 'up') {
          direction = 'down';
          console.log('down');
        }
        break;
    }
  };


}))(drawModule);

const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const snakeSize = 10;
let w = 350;
let h = 350;
let score = 0;
let snake;
let food;
let loop = 80;
let snakecolor = 'black';
let snakeborder = '#9acc99';
let eatcolor = '#9acc99';
let eatborder = 'black';
let text_color = 'black';

const drawModule = ((() => {

  const bodySnake = (x, y) => {
    ctx.fillStyle = snakecolor;
    ctx.fillRect(x * snakeSize, y * snakeSize, snakeSize, snakeSize);
    ctx.strokeStyle = snakeborder;
    ctx.strokeRect(x * snakeSize, y * snakeSize, snakeSize, snakeSize);
  };

  const eat = (x, y) => {
    ctx.fillStyle = eatcolor;
    ctx.fillRect(x * snakeSize, y * snakeSize, snakeSize, snakeSize);
    ctx.fillStyle = eatborder;
    ctx.fillRect(x * snakeSize + 1, y * snakeSize + 1, snakeSize - 2, snakeSize - 2);
  };

  scoreText = () => {
    const score_text = 'Score:' + score;
    ctx.fillStyle = text_color;
    ctx.fillText(score_text, 145, h - 5);
  };

  gameOver = () => {
    const score_text = 'You lose, try again';
    ctx.fillStyle = text_color;
    ctx.font = "14px Arial";
    ctx.fillText(score_text, 120, h - 200);
  };

  restartText = () => {
    const score_text = 'Will we start again? Are you sure?';
    ctx.fillStyle = text_color;
    ctx.font = "14px Arial";
    ctx.fillText(score_text, 70, h - 200);
  };

  const drawSnake = () => {
    const length = 1;
    snake = [];
    for (let i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      snake.push(
        {
          x: i,
          y: 0
        });
    }
  };

  const paint = () => {
    ctx.fillStyle = snakeborder;
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
    ctx.strokeStyle = snakecolor;
    ctx.strokeRect(0, 0, w, h);

    btn.setAttribute('disabled', true);

    let snakeX = snake[0].x;
    let snakeY = snake[0].y;

    if (direction == 'right') {
      snakeX++;
    }
    else if (direction == 'left') {
      snakeX--;
    }
    else if (direction == 'up') {
      snakeY--;
    } else if (direction == 'down') {
      snakeY++;
    }

    if (snakeX == -1 || snakeX == w / snakeSize || snakeY == -1 || snakeY == h / snakeSize || checkCollision(snakeX, snakeY, snake)) {

      btn.removeAttribute('disabled', true);
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
      gameloop = clearInterval(gameloop);
      gameOver();

      return;
    }

    if (snakeX == food.x && snakeY == food.y) {
      var tail = {
        x: snakeX,
        y: snakeY
      };
      score++;
      createEat();
    } else {
      var tail = snake.pop();
      tail.x = snakeX;
      tail.y = snakeY;
    }

    snake.unshift(tail);

    for (let i = 0; i < snake.length; i++) {
      bodySnake(snake[i].x, snake[i].y);
    }

    eat(food.x, food.y);
    scoreText();
  };

  let reset = document.getElementById('btn-restart');
  reset.addEventListener("click", () => {
    btn.removeAttribute('disabled', true);
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
    gameloop = clearInterval(gameloop);
    score = 0;
    restartText();
  });

  let createEat = () => {
    food = {
      x: Math.floor((Math.random() * 30) + 1),
      y: Math.floor((Math.random() * 30) + 1)
    };

    for (let i = 0; i > snake.length; i++) {
      const snakeX = snake[i].x;
      const snakeY = snake[i].y;

      if (food.x === snakeX && food.y === snakeY || food.y === snakeY && food.x === snakeX) {
        food.x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 30) + 1);
        food.y = Math.floor((Math.random() * 30) + 1);
      }
    }
  };


  var checkCollision = (x, y, array) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      if (array[i].x === x && array[i].y === y)
        return true;
    }
    return false;
  };

  init = () => {

    direction = 'right';
    drawSnake();
    createEat();
    gameloop = setInterval(paint, loop);

  };

  return {
    init
  };

})());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для задержки требуются две переменные: `defaultLoopDelay` и `currentLoopDelay`. Одна для начальной скорости, вторая - для текущей.

Выносим таймер `gameloop` в глобальную область, чтобы можно было переустановить его из `paint()` с новой задержкой.

Определяем переменную `speedBoost`, содержащую значение, на которое будет уменьшаться задержка.
Определяем переменную `foodForBoost`, содержащую количество еды необходимое съесть до каждого ускорения.
Определяем переменную `foodRemainForBoost`, содержащую количество еды, которое осталось съесть до ближайшего ускорения, и инициализируем её значением `foodForBoost`.

После каждого приема пищи уменьшаем на единицу `foodRemainForBoost`. Если `foodRemainForBoost` становится `0`, то устанавливаем её в `foodForBoost`, уменьшаем `currentLoopDelay` на `speedBoost`, останавливаем текущий таймер и запускаем новый с обновленным интервалом.

При каждом вызове `init()` сбрасываем `currentLoopDelay` в `defaultLoopDelay`.

Пример: https://jsfiddle.net/wsbvfmzr/1/

Answer (score -2):

Попробуйте так:

```
if( x == 0){x++;  } else() { x+=5}
```